# How to improve the personality extraction accuracy?

Tags: python, nltk

I read an article, named Unsupervised Personality Recognition for Social Network Sites, about the personality extraction from text. There are 22 features and 4 classes represented 4 personalities. Through counting the features in a text, we can know which class this sentence belong to, which means we can know the personality of the sentence. 
The article provides the correlations for every feature and class. So the score of a class is the feature's value minus the mean of all feature's value then divided by the standard deviation of all feature's value then multiply the correlation coefficiency provided by the article. Then we can judge if the sentence belongs to the class through its score. I set the threshold to improve its accuracy but it is still not good enough. My result is around 50-60% accuracy and don't know how to improve it. Anyone can help me ?

```
import csv
import re
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize, RegexpTokenizer
import pickle
from statistics import mean, stdev


with open('mypersonality_final.csv', newline = '') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    test = []
    for w in reader:
        test.append(w)

def all_punctuation(text):
    punctuations = ['.', ',', ';', ':']
    count = 0
    for w in text:
        if w in punctuations:
            count += 1
    return count

def count_commas(text):
    count = 0
    for w in text:
        if w == ',':
            count += 1
    return count

def count_pattern(text):
    grammar = RegexpTokenizer(r'\@')
    pattern = grammar.tokenize(text)
    return len(pattern)

def count_exclamation(text):
    grammar = RegexpTokenizer(r'\!')
    pattern = grammar.tokenize(text)
    return len(pattern)

def ex_links(text):
    grammar = RegexpTokenizer(r'http?\S+\w(?:(?:\/[^\s/]*))*|www\.\S+\w(?:(?:\/[^\s/]*))*|ftp\S+\w(?:(?:\/[^\s/]*))*')
    pattern = grammar.tokenize(text)
    return len(pattern)

def firs_sinpronouns(text):
    sigpronouns = ['i', 'me', 'my', 'mine', 'we']
    count = 0
    for w in text:
        if w.lower() in sigpronouns:
            count += 1
    return count

def negative_particle(text):
    with open('negative-words.txt') as neg:
        neg = neg.read()
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(neg)
    grammar = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
    nopunctuation = grammar.tokenize(text)
    count = 0
    for w in nopunctuation:
        if w.lower() in words:
            count += 1
    return count

def negative_emoticon(text):
    grammar = RegexpTokenizer(r"(?::|;|=)(?:-)?(?:\()")
    emoticons = grammar.tokenize(text)
    return len(emoticons)

def numbers(text):
    grammar = RegexpTokenizer(r'\d+')
    pattern = grammar.tokenize(text)
    return len(pattern)

def parenthesis(text):
    pat = '\([^)]*\)'
    parent = re.findall(pat, text)
    return len(parent)

def positive_emoticon(text):
    grammar = RegexpTokenizer(r'(?::|;|=|<|>)(?:-|\.)?(?:\)|D|P|3|<)')
    emoticons = grammar.tokenize(text)
    return len(emoticons)

def prepositions(text):
    tagged = nltk.pos_tag(text)
    count = 0
    for w in tagged:
        if w[1] == 'IN':
            count += 1
    return count

def pronouns(text):
    tagged = nltk.pos_tag(text)
    count = 0
    for w in tagged:
        if (w[1] == 'PRP' or w[1] == 'PRP$' or w[1] == 'WP' or w[1] == 'WPR$'):
            count += 1
    return count

def count_question(text):
    grammar = RegexpTokenizer(r'\?')
    pattern = grammar.tokenize(text)
    return len(pattern)

def long_words(text):
    grammar = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w{7,}')
    pattern = grammar.tokenize(text)
    return len(pattern)

def firs_pronouns(text):
    firstpronouns = ['i', 'me', 'my', 'mine', 'we', 'our', 'ours', 'us']
    count = 0
    for w in text:
        if w.lower() in firstpronouns:
            count += 1
    return count

def swears_count(text):
    with open('swears.txt') as test:
        words = test.read()
        swears = re.sub(r'[^\w+\s]+', '', words)
        swears = swears.split('\n')
        count = 0
    for w in text:
        if w.lower() in swears:
            count += 1
    return count

def typetoken_ratio(text):
    typed = set(text)
    token = text
    ratio = len(typed)/len(token)
    return ratio

def count_words(text):
    grammar = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
    pattern = grammar.tokenize(text)
    return len(pattern)

def firs_pluralpronouns(text):
    pluralpronouns = ['we', 'our', 'ours', 'us']
    count = 0
    for w in text:
        if w.lower() in pluralpronouns:
            count += 1
    return count

def sec_pronouns(text):
    secpronouns = ['you', 'your', 'yours']
    count = 0
    for w in text:
        if w.lower() in secpronouns:
            count += 1
    return count

def mean_freq(text):
##    grammar = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
    words = word_tokenize(text)
    wordsl = []
    for w in words:
        wordsl.append(w.lower())
    unique = set(wordsl)
    return (len(wordsl)/len(unique))


def mean_std(test):
    f1 = []
    f2 = []
    f3 = []
    f4 = []
    f5 = []
    f6 = []
    f7 = []
    f8 = []
    f9 = []
    f10 = []
    f11 = []
    f12 = []
    f13 = []
    f14 = []
    f15 = []
    f16 = []
    f17 = []
    f18 = []
    f19 = []
    f20 = []
    f21 = []
    f22 = []
    for w in test[1:]:
        f1.append(all_punctuation(word_tokenize(w[1])))
        f2.append(count_commas(word_tokenize(w[1])))
        f3.append(count_pattern(w[1]))
        f4.append(count_exclamation(w[1]))
        f5.append(ex_links(w[1]))
        f6.append(firs_sinpronouns(word_tokenize(w[1])))
        f7.append(negative_particle(w[1]))
        f8.append(negative_emoticon(w[1]))
        f9.append(numbers(w[1]))
        f10.append(parenthesis(w[1]))
        f11.append(positive_emoticon(w[1]))
        f12.append(prepositions(word_tokenize(w[1])))
        f13.append(pronouns(word_tokenize(w[1])))
        f14.append(count_question(w[1]))
        f15.append(long_words(w[1]))
        f16.append(firs_pronouns(word_tokenize(w[1])))
        f17.append(swears_count(word_tokenize(w[1])))
        f18.append(typetoken_ratio(word_tokenize(w[1])))
        f19.append(count_words(w[1]))
        f20.append(firs_pluralpronouns(word_tokenize(w[1])))
        f21.append(sec_pronouns(word_tokenize(w[1])))
        f22.append(mean_freq(w[1]))
    value = [f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, f11, f12, f13, f14, f15, f16, f17, f18, f19, f20, f21, f22]
    mean1 = []
    stdev1 = []
    for a in value:
        mean1.append(round(mean(a),2))
        stdev1.append(round(stdev(a),2))
    return (mean1, stdev1)

##save_file = open('sample_value.pickle', 'wb')
##pickle.dump(mean_std(test), save_file)
##save_file.close()
savedfile = open('sample_value.pickle', 'rb')
trained = pickle.load(savedfile)
savedfile.close()

def evaluation(test):
    ne = 0
    ns = 0
    na = 0
    nc = 0
    no = 0
    for w in test[1:]:
        z1 = (all_punctuation(word_tokenize(w[1])) - trained[0][0])/(trained[1][0])
        z2 = (count_commas(word_tokenize(w[1]))- trained[0][1])/(trained[1][1])
        z3 = (count_pattern(w[1]) - trained[0][2])/(trained[1][2])
        z4 = (count_exclamation(w[1]) - trained[0][3])/(trained[1][3])
        z5 = (ex_links(w[1]) - trained[0][4])/(trained[1][4])
        z6 = (firs_sinpronouns(word_tokenize(w[1]))- trained[0][5])/(trained[1][5])
        z7 = (negative_particle(w[1])-trained[0][6])/(trained[1][6])
        z8 = (negative_emoticon(w[1]) - trained[0][7])/(trained[1][7])
        z9 = (numbers(w[1])-trained[0][8])/(trained[1][8])
        z10 = (parenthesis(w[1])-trained[0][9])/(trained[1][9])
        z11 = (positive_emoticon(w[1])-trained[0][10])/(trained[1][10])
        z12 = (prepositions(word_tokenize(w[1]))-trained[0][11])/(trained[1][11])
        z13 = (pronouns(word_tokenize(w[1]))-trained[0][12])/(trained[1][12])
        z14 = (count_question(w[1])-trained[0][13])/(trained[1][13])
        z15 = (long_words(w[1])-trained[0][14])/(trained[1][14])
        z16 = (firs_pronouns(word_tokenize(w[1]))-trained[0][15])/(trained[1][15])
        z17 = (swears_count(word_tokenize(w[1]))-trained[0][16])/(trained[1][16])
        z18 = (typetoken_ratio(word_tokenize(w[1]))-trained[0][17])/(trained[1][17])
        z19 = (count_words(w[1])-trained[0][18])/(trained[1][18])
        z20 = (firs_pluralpronouns(word_tokenize(w[1]))-trained[0][19])/(trained[1][19])
        z21 = (sec_pronouns(word_tokenize(w[1]))-trained[0][20])/(trained[1][20])
        z22 = (mean_freq(w[1])-trained[0][21])/(trained[1][21])
        E = -0.08*z1-0.02*z2-0.07*z3-0.05*z5+0.05*z6-0.08*z7-0.03*z8-0.03*z9-0.06*z10+0.07*z11+0.07*z13-0.06*z14-0.06*z15+0.07*z16-0.01*z17-0.05*z18-0.01*z19+0.06*z20-0.01*z21+0.05*z22
        S = -0.04*z1+0.01*z2+0.02*z3-0.05*z4-0.02*z5-0.15*z6+0.12*z7-0.18*z8+0.05*z9+0.03*z10+0.07*z11+0.06*z12+0.12*z13-0.05*z14+0.06*z15-0.14*z16+0.1*z18+0.02*z19+0.07*z20+0.03*z21-0.06*z22
        A = -0.01*z1-0.02*z2+0.01*z3+0.06*z4-0.01*z5+0.05*z6+0.11*z7-0.11*z8-0.03*z9-0.04*z10+0.05*z11+0.04*z12+0.04*z13-0.04*z14-0.05*z15-0.06*z16-0.14*z17-0.04*z18+0.02*z19+0.04*z20-0.06*z21+0.03*z22
        C = -0.04*z1-0.01*z2+0.01*z3-0.03*z5+0.04*z6-0.07*z7-0.11*z8-0.02*z9-0.01*z10+0.02*z11+0.08*z12+0.02*z13-0.06*z14+0.02*z15-0.04*z16-0.11*z17-0.05*z18-0.02*z19+0.01*z20-0.04*z21+0.06*z22
        O = -10*z1+0.1*z2+0.06*z3-0.03*z4+0.09*z5-0.14*z6+0.01*z7+0.04*z8-0.06*z9+0.1*z10+0.02*z11-0.04*z12-0.06*z13+0.08*z14+0.1*z15-0.14*z16+0.08*z17+0.09*z18+0.06*z19+0.04*z20+0.11*z21-0.07*z22

        if E>0.65:
            if w[7] =='y':
                ne+=1
        if E<0.65:
            if w[7]=='n':
                ne+=1
        if S>0.75:
            if w[8] == 'y':
                ns +=1
        if S<0.75:
            if w[8] == 'n':
                ns+=1
        if A>0.005:
            if w[9]=='y':
                na+=1
        if A<0.005:
            if w[9]=='n':
                na+=1
        if C>0.58:
            if w[10]=='y':
                nc+=1
        if C<0.58:
            if w[10]=='n':
                nc+=1
        if O>(-0.05):
            if w[11]=='y':
                no+=1
        if O<(-0.05):
            if w[11]=='n':
                no+=1       
    print (round((ne/9917)*100,2), round((ns/9917)*100,2),round((na/9917)*100,2),round((nc/9917)*100,2),round((no/9917)*100,2))

evaluation(test)
```

The sample data is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFmh3.png)

Comment: Instead of using a fixed formula with hard-coded weights (that's what I understand you are doing), you could try training a classifier on those features, eg. an SVM (support vector machine).

Comment: The authors of the published article have (presumably) put some non-trivial effort to getting their performance to its current level. If you have matched their performance but need to do better, you'll need to put in the same kind of effort and time. Random guesses by us SO readers are no substitute.